# Retrieve hidden field value when colorbox repoens

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a popup window on a form wherein values are submitted via ajax call. I am getting response as  json and everything works fine. But once the popup window (colorbox) is closed, the values are lost. I want to preserve the values on the popup window till the main form is submitted.

Can anyone please suggest something?

I could store value in an html hidden variable but I want to access it as a ruby variable so that I can use that for active record.

Comment: for better understanding add related code

Answer (score 0):

Create global variables for your needed values.
Handle submit event for form or change for colorbox and change this variables

Example

```
var MY_GLOBAL_VALUE = 1;

$(window).ready(function(){
 $("form").submit(function(e){
   MY_GLOBAL_VALUE = $('#colorbox').attr('my_value');
 });
});
```